# Is there anything wrong with allowing moss to grow around herbs?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, herbs, moss

I've started up a pot of Basil sprouts indoors under a lamp, and it seems like some moss is beginning to grow around them.  Is there anything wrong with having moss in the same pot?  Any problems with competition, or weird flavorings?

Comment: Indoors, moss will compete with seedlings and hinder their growth.  For outdoors moss is a great addition where you can get it to grow.

Comment: Interesting - what makes the difference between indoors and outdoors?

Comment: Competition from other plants, access to water, not too hot, not too cold.  This would be a good question to ask..

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for clarification on your original comment - why is moss indoors bad, while moss outdoors is fine?

Comment: With seedlings they need all the help they can get to grow. Outdoors, moss tends to be out competed by other plants and has to be nurtured along if you want to cultivate it

Comment: Ah, so it's more about the relative strengths of the plants, rather than specifically being indoors or outdoors

Comment: Have had same issue with an outdoor thyme plant but the moss doesn't seem to be hurting anything.

Comment: Moss is an opportunist.  If there is bare soil, proper moisture and spores present you will get 'mosses'.  This is one reason we don't use garden soil for potted plants.  What are you using for fertilizer? Did you use sterilized potting soil?  I'd pull the moss up from around the seedlings.  Careful using too much fertilizer with seedlings, especially indoors.  If the seedlings get too long and gangly, they aren't getting enough light.  If you haven't used potting soil, I'd consider transplanting the starts into tiny pots with potting soil, keep moist, not wet and a plastic dome helps humidity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moss on an indoor pot is a sign that the mix surface is constantly damp, and that isn't good. Use a fork or toothpick or something, and stir up the top layer to get rid of it. Always allow the top 1/2" or so to dry between waterings.

Competition shouldn't be a problem except for very small seedlings, and the flavor should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The moss you are talking about is bad any way you look at it:

- It must stay wet to grow, so it will harbor fungi.
- It will take nutrients away from the plant you are trying to grow.
- Some bugs use it for a place to lay eggs.

To get rid of it, lightly pinch it out and replace with dry fresh dirt. Do not stir it back in the dirt, because when the conditions get right again it will just start to grow again.

Comment: If you allow the top 1/2" of mix to dry between waterings, the moss won't be a problem.